# Dashboard is printing in mobile device size (undesirable viewer port) but i want to be printing in desktop size

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, leaflet, dashboard, quasar

I have been trying to print **custom dashboard** composed of **high-charts**, **leaflet map** and **cards** to fit one page using js but its printing in mobile view port. The problem is that when i print its printing in mobile size / view port which is making it to overflow to other pages instead of fitting to one page. After i failed printing i tried converting it to PDF using js-pdf but no fortunes.

The Dashboard has built using Quasar and Vuejs

Thanks for your assistance in advance

Comment: How does the CSS for the [box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model) that you want printed look like? Are there any [paged media CSS rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media) or `@media print`-specific CSS rules applied? What's the desired paper size? Landscape or portrait?

Comment: needed device orientation is landscape and the page should be looking as its rendering on 1920x1080 device. When am rendering on 1920x1080 its rendering but when i try to print  on the same device its turning to mobile size (during printing) then after printing its turning back to big screen size

Comment: It's hard to point at anything specific without seeing your CSS code, so with the information you provid you're gonna get generic advice such as: read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing , use `@media print` in your stylesheets, and when printing think in [*centimeters* (or *inches*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Numbers_lengths_and_percentages) instead of [*pixels*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_pixel) (you don't want 1920x1080px, but ~25x20cm instead).

Comment: Its quasar framework (vue js) i used class based stying as its specified in its documentation e.g each component i could give it col-md, col-xl, col-sm,col-lg to make  it change depending on screen size but now when i  open the dashboard on desktop its rendering correctly but when i try to print thats when the dashboard changes to mobile rendering but i havent added any media queries. If this fails i feel you may suggest the best browser based npm which i can use to take screenshot  NB: there is also leaflet map on the dashboard

Comment: @IvanSanchez thanks so much for your responses hoping to get more

Comment: I didn't ask for clarification on whether *you added* CSS media queries. I asked if there are any rules in CSS media queries *being applied*, which is (very) different.

Comment: I have decided to use dom-to-image library to take screenshots and its working perfectly as i wanted just any type of export i clinged to printing as i thought it will be easier @IvanSanchez Thanks so much

Comment: You have used the Highcharts tag, but it seems that your issue is not related to functionality of this library.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel i had to detail all the problem space as it could be highcharts problem of not printing properly thats why i had to tag all what felt could be the problem

Comment: I understand, but Highcharts charts are fully responsive and they should adjust the size to parent `div` which you have set to import by using other tools.

Comment: ok fine this noted @SebastianWędzel